# Bluetooth APIs to detect radio on\off of a remote device

Tags: bluetooth

Currently i am using Bluetooth APIs meant for Microsoft bluetooth stack. I have developed an bluetooth PC application in C++ which discovers remote bluetooth device and then authenticate device through some API. Problem is when i turn off bluetooth radio from remote device and then start searching the device again through PC application, API still detects the remote device even if remote device radio is turned off.

I suspect device cache which is part of OS is not getting updated. So API returns the same device name.

Any help in finding why device is not updated and also any pointers to bluetooth API would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What API are you using?  There's the 'unknown', 'remembered' and 'authenticated' flags.  Which with WSALookupService... are output in the dwOutputFlags field for instance, see [Bluetooth and WSAQUERYSET for Device Inquiry (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362918.aspx)

Unfortunately that means there's no way to get "devices (in discoverable-mode) in range". :-(  See more info at "Listing Discoverable devices only" in my document [Bluetooth in Windows 7](http://www.alanjmcf.me.uk/comms/bluetooth/Bluetooth%20in%20Windows%207.html), in particular in the footnote.

Answer (score 1):

If you need some ideas on how to handle this problem you should look at the in the hand bluetooth library (source avaible) to understand how they do.
http://32feet.net/
I use that library and I can get a list of remote devices (prevoiusly paired) in range.

Answer (score 0):

The device gets added in the list of authenticated devices after authentication.
You need to remove your device first from this list.

So before searching for device again you can use BluetoothFindFirstDevice and BluetoothFindNexttDevice to loop through list of authenticated devices.Filter your device on the basis of class or friendlyname and remove it by calling BluetoothRemoveDevice.

Next time if you call Authentication API when device is off, it will fail giving timeout error.Now you know device is off!!